# Android application experiencing strange layout when setting activity background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

[Here is the layout image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkzYK.png)

The code that's causing the issue is as follows

```
View parent = calculateButton.getRootView();
Parent.setBackgroundColor(appSettings.getInt("app_background",r.color.White);
```

It works fine once the qpp key is there. However, the default key, no matter what it is, causes the layout bug.

I'm testing on a Nexus 6

EDIT: I believe i have solved it by replacing the default value for my getInt with an actual integer value rather than R.color.COLOR

Comment: I recall seeing severe rendering issues similar to yours and they were  related to hardware acceleration. As debugging step, please try disabling hardware acceleration for this particular activity and see if the issue persists: <activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />

Comment: EDIT: still having some issues.

Comment: I think i solved it. I was using r.color.white in my preferences getInt. when I pass in the integer value, i no longer get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the root cause is, but it seems that whenever I used a color picker to set the color of the layout, it caused this weird rendering issue. I removed the feature, because I couldn't get it to render properly when the color was changed while the app was running.